# RegExp to get src form url

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I have this string:

```
<img class="ui mini avatar image" src="http://graph.facebook.com/fsdgfdgfdgsdfgdfgdfg564d6/picture/?type=large">
facebook
```

Like this, how can i ghet only the url from that string? only this part

```
http://graph.facebook.com/fsdgfdgfdgsdfgdfgdfg564d6/picture/?type=large
```

Comment: You don't need to use regex for this. Check my answer.

Comment: If you are actually trying to match the URL in the literal string, then `/http[^\"]+/i` will do the job. However, if you are trying to get the src of an element in a page, then `document.images[0].src` will return the value of the *src* property of the first image in the document. There are other ways of selecting img elements that do not require a library (and are much faster).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use jQuery, you can do this:

```
var sourceUrl = $('.image').attr('src'); // Here I'm accessing by class name.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the the window.location object

```
window.location.host
// gives "graph.facebook.com"
window.location.pathname
// gives "/fsdgfdgfdgsdfgdfgdfg564d6/picture/"
window.location.search
// gives "?type=large"
```

The MDN site says all this is supported in all browsers https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location?type=large

Comment: Read question again. You are going in different direction

Comment: @SimpleMan you are correct. I must have missed the regex part in the question title. Cheers.